# How do I use the name of the picture (It's already in "drawable") for use in the program?

Tags: kotlin, android-drawable

I tried to do it through "string" but it doesn't work. How to do it?

```
var TestString : String = "test1.png"
var TestId : Int = R.drawable.TestString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```kotlin
val resId = applicationContext.resources.getIdentifier("test1", "drawable", applicationContext.packageName) 

yourImageView.setImageResource(resId)
```

Comment: I have a lot of images with names like "test1, test2, .." and need to process them.
I know that I need the ID of each image, but how do I get them from the filenames?

Comment: I showed you how to pull a single one. Similarly, maybe you can for loop and solve it. I'm not sure about that. @RealyJuniorGuy